# Unable to build opencv ios framework for architecture arm64 and x86_64

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I am following a opencv installation document [Installation in iOS](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html) when compile a ios framework. However, if I did not change `platform/ios/build_framework.py` and build the framework, I will have the following errors:

```
build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = x86_64
    IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator6.1

Build Preparation
Build task concurrency set to 8 via user default IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks

=== BUILD AGGREGATE TARGET ZERO_CHECK OF PROJECT OpenCV WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies


=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET zlib OF PROJECT OpenCV WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET libjpeg OF PROJECT OpenCV WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

** BUILD FAILED **

Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = x86_64
    IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator6.1

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET zlib OF PROJECT OpenCV WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).


** BUILD FAILED **
```

Then, after many tries, I found that if I only compile for architecture armv7, armv7s and i386 by changing the following scripts in `platform/ios/build_framework.py` the framework can be built successfully.

```
targets = ["iPhoneOS", "iPhoneOS", "iPhoneSimulator"] #"iPhoneOS", "iPhoneSimulator"
    archs = ["armv7", "armv7s", "i386"]#"arm64", , "x86_64"
    for i in range(len(targets)):
        build_opencv(srcroot, os.path.join(dstroot, "build"), targets[i], archs[i])
```

Any ideas on how I can compile for the arm64 and x86_64 architecture? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the i386 and compile for armv7,armv7s, and arm64 - these are the architecture option for Xcode for 64 bit - iphone5s.

Do not mix intel and arm specification they will not and cannot mix.  The architecture command is to inform the compiler on how the object code will be created.  Because intel is a CISC processor and arm is a RISC internally their object codes are very different.
a MOVE command for example may generate an x'80'opcode (command instruction) for intel but an x'60'for ARM. far as I know an i386 is the old intel 32 bit architecture, Xcode maybe doing some magic to have universal object codes that can run on both intel and RISC if it is doing so - it will not be efficient, it will always be better to compile to specific architectures.

The 32 bit, 64 bit 128 ..... are addressing modes - they are also the size of the processor registers and determine how much memory (RAM) can be accessed by the CPU. In general, aside from the ability to have huge RAM, higher bit processors will usually reduce the number of instructions to do a particular task.

Because downward compatibility is usually built in, an app compiled for armv6 will typically run in armv7 or even arm64 in compatibility mode but it will not be able to harness the advantages of running a true 64 bit application.

The targets is a higher level specification which specifies which commands can be used  for example an iPad has UIPopViewController but this is not supported in an iPhone or an iPod touch.

One last thing - only iPhone 5s works with arm64 if you set another target it will probably flag arm64 as not an option.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are compiling for x86_64 architecture, that is for OS X (laptop or mac tower), NOT iOS (iPad, iPhone).

What are you using? Not Xcode I presume?

You don't need to compile to x86_64 unless you want this to run on a 64-bit mac laptop or desktop... & it doesn't seem like you are trying to do that by your question?

Also, if you have it for i386 it is probably compatible with most OS X machines -- it will just run in 32-bit not 64-bit.

As far as arm64, that is also probably 64-bit. You might not have the libraries for 64-bit? Is your machine running on 64-bit? Check the opencv libraries (dynamic or static?) & see if they are 32 or 64? If they are 32-bit then that is the problem. You'll need to build them as 64-bit libraries or find them as such. I can't give you anymore info without knowing what platform you are on.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am now compiling for ios(ipad and iphone) with xcode. In fact my mac is 64-bit desktop, so my machine can run on 64-bit.

Comment: iPhone 5s is also 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned that OpenCV for iOS has been added to [CocoaPods](http://www.cocoapods.org). You can see the podspec [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/OpenCV/2.4.3/OpenCV.podspec) and the Github repository [here](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/OpenCV-iOS). With CocoaPods, you create a file named `Podfile` in the root of your project and paste in this line:

```
pod 'OpenCV'
```

Save the file and run `pod install` from the terminal (assuming that CocoaPods is installed of course).

I have this running on my iPhone 5S, which is 64 bit as well.