# How to upload iOS app to Appstore which uses OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm current developing iOS apps with OpenCV. But When I want to upload app to app store it occurs error like this Missing 64 bit support, iOS apps submitted to App Store must include 64 bit support and be built with iOS 8 SDK or later.

But as I know, OpenCV doesn't support 64 bit (ARM 64). And it occurs error when I changed architecture setting (add ARM 64) in build settings like Exit With Code 1

I tried with the latest version but it occurs error like this. `Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_MW_exitHandler", referenced from: -[BackgroundObject stopBackground] in BackgroundObject.o`.
My concern is that how can I upload app to app store which uses OpenCV which doesn't support 64 bit version.

Comment: You can't.  It's not a technical limitation, so no one here can help you get around it.  Get OpenCV to compile for arm64.  That's your answer.

Comment: @Avi Thanks for your answer, Btw How can I get OpenCV to compile for arm64?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246726/unable-to-build-opencv-ios-framework-for-architecture-arm64-and-x86-64.